# How to start a new android activity that is smaller than the full screen

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

For a current android application I'm developing, I need to display some integer values on the screen after the user clicks a set of buttons. Essentially, I want to have a blocked space on the screen that will always display the numbers.

I'm at a loss for how to approach this problem, I originally just made use of the toast function for the display but that only lasts for a few seconds and doesn't change as buttons are pressed live.

Instead, I've been attempting to create a new activity which will only take up a fraction of the screen (maybe the top 10%). **I know how to create a new Android Activity which opens a new page, but is there any way to create an activity that can overlay on the current page, and is smaller than the screen size?**

Thanks so much.

Comment: [Fragments?](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create an additional `Activity`.  Use the same `Activity` that your buttons are on.

You can add a `TextView` to your display that can be used for displaying the values and/or text (Position it on the screen how you want, and you can also set the desired size).  This isn't the only option, but is pretty simple to use.

You can then add in methods to generate a `String` based off of the actions performed on the buttons.  After generating the `String`, you can update the text of the `TextView` with it.

[Text View Doc.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use Fragments. It Has its own Life Cycle works similar to a Activity-

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html